# What Am I? (easy)

Tags: riddle

What am I?

You may not think of me as fruity, but I have fruit.

You may not think of me as milky, but I contain dairy.

You may not think of me as healthy, but I have vegetables.

You may not think of me as bird food, but I do have seeds.

You may not think of me as grainy, but I have grains.

Hint:

> I am a meal

Another hint:

> You can find me at almost every American restaurant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Honestly there's probably a ton of food stuff that fits, but I'm gonna guess..

> A burger?

You may not think of me as fruity, but I have fruit.

> Tomatoes are fruits. Ketchup is made of tomatoes. Loses most of the 'fruity'-ness, but fruit nonetheless.

You may not think of me as milky, but I contain dairy.

> Cheese is a common ingredient in burgers. Not very milky there either.

You may not think of me as healthy, but I have vegetables.

> Pickles, lettuce, you name it. But burgers/fast food are usually seen as the opposite of healthy.

You may not think of me as bird food, but I do have seeds.

> Sesame seeds on top of the bun. But you won't feed birds whole burgers, would you?

You may not think of me as grainy, but I have grains.

> Bread.

Comment: Your answer is correct!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is a

> Custard, as it a blend of grains, vegetables, fruits in a milk/dairy base.

Comment: Not quite, but you are going in the right direction.